# Confidence intervals for dependent proportions

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, proportion, independence

I have a strange dataset and I need some help calculating confidence intervals for proportions, with an unorthodox dependence structure. I have been constrained to the following setup, and I have no idea how to proceed. This is not a modelling study.

This dataset is a set of images, ordered in time. For illustration, let’s say the images are of dogs in parks, and we have four breeds: golden retriever, German shepherd, chihuahua, and shih tzu.

*EDITED* based on a comment - thanks

- Each image contains at least one dog, but not necessarily one of each breed.
- Each image may contain a maximum of one of each breed of dog.
- Each dog within an image may be sitting or standing, and whether one dog is sitting does not affect the probability that any other dog within the image will sit.
- Not every park will have every breed of dog.

This dataset is partitioned into two categories, A and B.

Suppose:

- Parks are indexed p=1,…,20
- Categories are indexed A and B
- Dog breeds are indexed b=1,2,3,4
- Groups (to be discussed shortly) are indexed g=1,2

Suppose each park p has n_p images, and some parks will not be included in the analysis.

From this set of 20 parks, we also group some images in the following way.

The first image that contains a specific dog breed at park p is part of “group 1” for that dog breed.

If you were indexing this, you might consider “golden retriever” breed 1 (b_1), and have g_1b_1p_1, g_1b_1p_2, …, g_1b_1p20. Then “German shepherd” would be breed 2 (b_2), and we would have g_1b_2p_1, g_1b_2p_2,…, g_1b_2p_20, etc.

One and only one subsequent appearance of that same dog breed at that same park is part of “group 2”. That is, suppose there are 5 subsequent appearances of golden retrievers at park 1; pick one of these images at random, and this is part of group 2 for the golden retrievers.

For example, suppose a golden retriever first appeared in image 3 of park 4 (so g_1b_1p_4 = “image 3 of park 4, which contains the first instance of a golden retriever at park 4”) and a golden retriever also appears in images 10, 12, and 150 of park 4. Pick one of these three images at random, and assign it to group 2 of the golden retrievers. That is, suppose we pick image 12. Then g_2b_1p_4 = “image 12 of park 4, which contains a subsequent instance of a golden retriever at park 4”.

However, an image that is in group 2 for one breed can be in group 1 for another breed and vice versa. For example, if a chihuahua is in image 12 of park 4 and had never previously appeared in park 4, then image 12 would be in group 1 for chihuahua, but would still be in group 2 for golden retriever.

Suppose there are n images in group 1 and n images in group 2. Notice that we do not necessarily have all parks represented in the groups, but the size of groups 1 and 2 will be the same.

A human was asked to look at each image and identify whether a pre-specified dog was sitting. Recall each breed may appear a maximum of once per image. The human knew which dog to focus on in the image. None of the other dogs were of interest - the person was instructed to focus on only one dog per image. Later, the same image may be presented again with another breed of interest.

Suppose we now have a table constructed in the following way of the proportion of dogs who were sitting (I've made up numbers here just to fill the table for illustration):

|  | Golden Retriever | German Shepherd | Chihuahua | Shih Tzu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Category A | 0.10 | 0.14 | 0.13 | 0.22 |
| Category B | 0.60 | 0.90 | 0.75 | 0.45 |
| Group 1 | 0.55 | 0.78 | 0.32 | 0.81 |
| Group 2 | 0.98 | 0.53 | 0.82 | 0.91 |

How can we obtain confidence intervals on each of these values?

Comment: The two statements "Each image may contain a maximum of one of each breed of dog." and "Each dog within an image is independent." appear to be contradictory. The first describes a form of dependence, the second denies it's there.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you, yes, this problem has been hard to specify. I'll edit it to say: "each image may contain a maximum of one of each breed of dog; dogs within an image may be sitting or standing, and whether one dog is sitting does not affect the probability that any other dog will sit".

Comment: How do you know that one dog sitting does not affect the probability that others will? Humans tend to sit down at a restaurant when the other humans in their party sit down, right?

Comment: @Dave That's true for humans and true for actual dog behaviour, yes - however, I'm trying to fit an analogy here. I'm not able to discuss the real research. Suffice to say there are 4 objects in an image and their positions are not affected by one another.

Comment: As so often happens, when people try to present a simplified/abstracted/obscured version of their problem by replacing its details with something different they either omit essential details or introduce details absent from the original, which interferes with our ability to offer useful help (it sure interferes with mine, at least).

Comment: I am with @Glen_b on this. If you really cannot get into more detail (that is possible), it will be difficult to give you good advice for a complex problem, given how common XY problems are. Perhaps your best bet is to vet a stastistical consultant for suitability to see confidential/proprietary information, have her sign an NDA, and work with her behind closed doors.

Comment: Thank you both. I understand the frustration. I wish I could be more forthcoming. It took me two days to draft this analogy, and as you can see it's imperfect. Are there any good resources you could point me to regarding confidence intervals for dependent proportions? The dependence structure is different from anything I've encountered before and I'm having trouble getting started.